# Averaging pixels in image ROI

Tags: python, image, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing

I have the following image and I would like to apply averaging on each masked region (**not the bounding box**) in the image.

[image]

As you can see, right now, the regions have changing values inside them on the heat map. Some pixels are yellowish, some are purplish. I want this to be not the case inside the masks.

So what I need to do is (I guess):

- to find which coordinates correspond to the masks
- average the pixels within these coordinates

Here is how the masks are found:

```
file_names = glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, "*.jpg"))
masks_prediction = np.zeros((521, 768, len(file_names)))
for i in range(len(file_names)):
    print(i)
    image = skimage.io.imread(file_names[i])
    predictions = model.detect([image],  verbose=1)
    p = predictions[0]
    masks = p['masks']
    merged_mask = np.zeros((masks.shape[0], masks.shape[1]))
    for j in range(masks.shape[2]):
        merged_mask[masks[:,:,j]==True] = True
        masks_prediction[:,:,i] = merged_mask
```

Here is the function which applies the masks:

```
def apply_mask(image, mask, color, alpha=0.5):
    """Apply the given mask to the image.
    """
    for c in range(3):
        image[:, :, c] = np.where(mask == 1,
                                  image[:, :, c] *
                                  (1 - alpha) + alpha * color[c] * 255,
                                  image[:, :, c])
    return image
```

and in the main file, here is how it is used:

```
mask = masks[:, :, i]
if show_mask:
     masked_image = apply_mask(masked_image, mask, color)
```

So I need to make a modification in somewhere here but I don't know where exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mask you are looking for is provided by the code :

```
mask = masks[:, :, i]
```

where *i* refers to the number of mask you have.

You can obtain the average values of the mask region from the original image using the openCV function `mean`

Here is how your code should look like:

```
mask = masks[:, :, i]
avg_masked_value = cv2.mean(original_image,mask)
```

where *original_image* is the original image you loaded and avg_masked_value will contain 3x1 array of averaged value.